# Developing an android app with gcm.

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, server, androidhttpclient

I am planning on developing an android application that sends a reminder and sets an alarm corresponding to that on other person's phone who has that app installed on his/her phone.
Now the reminder is actually a bundle of data that includes date/time and a message for that reminder.
The App is going to send a reminder bundle to a server and then the server will redirect the message on the intended person's phone. Now what i understand from this is that of a bi-directional communication.
I have studied Google Cloud Messaging HTTP and XMPP(CCS).
I'm confused which protocol is perfect for an app like mine.
Any help is of high regard.

Comment: XMPP is brilliant but comes with overheads. You have to have a dedicated server. As far as I'm aware the Google GCM is just a forwarding service to your server, not a dedicated server to handle messages itself. Your packets don't sound overly large though, so a simple JSON http packet would work, but then how would you address them? That's why XMPP would be better suited.

Comment: Yes i actually forgot to mention that. Indeed i'll be using a dedicated server and using GCM as an intermediary between my app and the server. Can't we address the packet to the specified user using HTTP?

Comment: Provided you have a way to address the packet yes, by which I mean maybe a persistent connection to an HTTP server, and just write to the socket. But XMPP reduces most of the work required in this respect. I'd originally opted for an in-house built server, but almost immediately realised the limitations. So, ended up implementing XMPP instead and I've never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Have your app register with GCM, send resulting token to server and bind it with user account. Your app sends the alarm settings to server along with to which user the alarm is for. You server looks up GCM token of the targeted user and send message to that device, your app, telling it to update its alarms from the server. Then your target app can e.g. register an alarm with AlarmManager or what ever suites your purpose.